# issue with escaping blanks? The system cannot find the path

Tags: python

the following code:

```
import os
dirPath = 'f:/x/finance-2020/AI/coursera-CNN/work/week4/Face\ Recognition/weights'
print(dirPath)
X = os.listdir(dirPath)
print(X)
```

fails as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    X = os.listdir(dirPath)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'f:/x/finance-2020/AI/courser
a-CNN/work/week4/Face\\ Recognition/weights'
```

However, when run in another directory it works:

```
import os
dirPath = 'f:/x/finance-2020/AI/coursera-CNN/work/week4'
print(dirPath)
X = os.listdir(dirPath)
print(X)

$ python test.py
f:/x/finance-2020/AI/coursera-CNN/work/week4
['Face Recognition', 'Neural Style Transfer', 'test.py']
```

I suspect a mistake in escaping the blank character, but don't know why it happens.

Comment: You don't need to escape spaces in path strings in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular string without escaping the space-

```py
dirPath = 'f:/x/finance-2020/AI/coursera-CNN/work/week4/Face Recognition/weights'
```

However, you may consider using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) operations for robust path building-

```py
dirPath = os.path.join('f:', os.sep, 'x', 'finance-2020', 'AI', 'coursera-CNN', 
'work', 'week4', 'Face Recognition', 'weights')
```

or rather, less verbosely, using `pathlib.Path`, as suggested by @Tomerikoo-

```py
from pathlib import Path
dirPath = Path('f:/x/finance-2020/AI/coursera-CNN/work/week4/Face Recognition/weights')
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say but your suggestion for using `os.path.join` like that is really not necessary... What *might* be better to do is use `pathlib.Path`